# How to set ons-tabbar-item active from javascript controller?

Tags: onsen-ui

I would like to set a tabbar active from javascript. I came across this article: http://onsenui.io/blog/onsen-ui-1-0-4-released/ that says to use:

```
$scope.ons.tabbar.setActiveTab(0);
```

I cant get this to work. Any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you use Onsen UI 1.1.2,

```
ons.tabbar.setActiveTab(0);
```

works. `$scope` is not necessary.